# PostgreSQL Count Number of Top Grades per Student

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have identification codes of students (Students.id) with grad High Distinction, HD, (Course_enrolments.grade) as below:

```
id  |  grade 
-------------
000 | HD  
000 | HD
001 | HD
010 | HD
010 | HD
010 | HD
010 | HD
100 | HD 
100 | HD 
110 | HD
```

with PostgreSQL commands, I want to query how many times each identification code occurs.

To get all students with HD grades, I used the following code.

```
select Students.id, Course_enrolments.grade
from Students
   join Course_enrolments on (Course_enrolments.student = Student.id)
where Course_enrolments.grade = 'HD'
```

Now I need to query how to calculate number of HD per student (per Student.id). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `count()` with `group by`

```
select Students.id, count(Course_enrolments.grade)
    from Students
       join Course_enrolments on (Course_enrolments.student = Student.id)
    where Course_enrolments.grade = 'HD'
group by Students.id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the number of HDs per student, then you an use *among those with course enrollements*:

```
select count(*) / count(distinct ce.student)
from Course_enrolments ce
where ce.grade = 'HD';
```

Note that the `join` is not necessary.

If you want the number averaged over *all* students, even those with no "HD", then you need the `students` table:

```
select count(ce.grade) / count(distinct s.id)
from students s left join
     course_enrolments ce
     on ce.student = s.id and ce.grade = 'HD';
```